# Plotting data with a string as the x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have the following dataset below in a pandas dataframe, and I am having trouble plotting the `timeOfDay` on the x-axis, and the `Wattage` on the y-axis.  Basically, I am trying to make a scatter plot (`plt.scatter`), with the x-axis with `3` points (Morning, Afternoon, Evening), and their respective `Wattages` above the `timeOfDay`.

So, `Morning` would have its three data points above it, `Afternoon` would have its data points above it, and so on.

```
  Wattage        time_stamp       timeOfDay
0    100      2015-02-24 10:00:00    Morning
1    120      2015-02-24 11:00:00    Morning
2    104      2015-02-24 12:00:00    Morning
3    105      2015-02-24 13:00:00  Afternoon
4    109      2015-02-24 14:00:00  Afternoon
5    120      2015-02-24 15:00:00  Afternoon
6    450      2015-02-24 16:00:00  Afternoon
7    200      2015-02-24 17:00:00    Evening
8    300      2015-02-24 18:00:00    Evening
9    190      2015-02-24 19:00:00    Evening
10   100      2015-02-24 20:00:00    Evening
11   110      2015-02-24 21:00:00    Evening
```

Comment: Maybe convert `Morning`, `Afternoon`, and `Evening` to 0, 1, and 2, respectfully. Then plot these numbers as X and the Wattage as Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [xticks](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) method:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.array( [100, 120, 104, 105, 109, 120, 450, 200, 300, 190, 100, 110] )

x = []   

labels = [ 'Morning', 'Morning','Morning','Afternoon','Afternoon','Afternoon','Afternoon', 'Evening', 'Evening', 'Evening', 'Evening', 'Evening']

for q in labels:
    if q == 'Morning':
        x.append(0)
    elif q == 'Afternoon':
        x.append(1)
    elif q == 'Evening':
        x.append(2)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.xticks( x, labels )
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a dataframe with your data in, you could easily use a [seaborn swarmplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html?highlight=swarmplot#seaborn.swarmplot), which makes this a one-liner:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

w = [100,123,156,90,40,320,198,174,175,146,238,120]
m = ["morning"]*4+ ["noon"]*4+["evening"]*4
df = pd.DataFrame({"Wattage" : w, "timeOfDay":m})

sns.swarmplot(x="timeOfDay", y="Wattage",  data=df)

plt.show()
```

[image]